# Automatically choose "line" in axis with stacked axis labels in R

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

Long story short, I'm creating a type of plot where on the x-axis, I have two different variables whose values are crossed with one another (in this minimal example, I have a=1,2 and b=1:5). I want to show how another variable (the one on the y axis) varies as a function of both a and b. What I'm trying to do is figure out a way to automatically place the second group of labels (in this case, the "b" variable). Here's a minimal example:

```
set.seed(1)
par(mar=c(7,3.5,1,1))
plot(1:10, 1:10+runif(10, -1, 1), xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", type="o")
axis(1, 1:10, rep(c("a=1", "a=2"), 5), las=2)
axis(1, seq(from=1.5, to=9.5, by=2), paste0("b=", 1:5), las=2, line=2, lwd=0)
```

Which produces the following graphic:
[image]

In this case, I got lucky and chose "line=2" as the correct placement. But if I modify things a bit (and make my variable labels a little more "bulky"):

```
set.seed(1)
par(mar=c(7,3.5,1,1))
plot(1:10, 1:10+runif(10, -1, 1), xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", type="o")
axis(1, 1:10, rep(c("Control", "Treatment"), 5), las=2)
axis(1, seq(from=1.5, to=9.5, by=2), paste0("b=", 1:5), las=2, line=2, lwd=0)
```

Now the groups of labels overlap:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically determine what "line" the axis is at so I can place my second group of labels without overlapping the first?

Comment: Have you thought about using `ggplot2`?

Comment: @AndrewBrēza - I have not. Can it do something like that?

Comment: It's generally the way to go if you're trying to make a super customized plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you could try. Instead of using `line`, which can be unreliable as you noted, you could pad white spaces to you second axis call using `sprintf`. Below, I first calculate the maximum number of characters in the first axis call, and multiply by 2.5, which seems to work well in this case. You might want to tweak this. Then, I use the default `line=1` but the with spaces will "push" the second axis call away from the axis line. BTW, you might want to do something like `max(nchar(first axis)) + max(nchar(second axis))` to calculate the padding.Finally, note that the "-" sign inside `sprintf` means add white spaces to the right.

```
set.seed(1)
par(mar=c(7,3.5,1,1))

max_nchar <- max(nchar(rep(c("Control", "Treatment"), 5))) *2.5

plot(1:10, 1:10+runif(10, -1, 1), xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", type="o")
axis(1, 1:10, rep(c("Control", "Treatment"), 5), las=2)
axis(1, seq(from=1.5, to=9.5, by=2), 
 sprintf(paste0("%-",max_nchar,"s"), paste0("b=", 1:5)), las=2, lwd=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I think that may end up working, but I'm having a bit of trouble. In the function I'm writing, the actual label is "skew". That seems to mess it up. So, if we do sprintf(paste0("%-",max_nchar,"s"), paste0("skew=", 1:5)), it comes out as "skew=                ", etc. without the 1-5. Any ideas why?

Comment: Okay, I just figured it out. It seems I ran out of character spacing. Changing the max_nchar multiple to a smaller number fixed it.